# iPhone- like tab bar in Android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In iPhone we can create a view that has a tab bar and make it the root view of the application then use the tab bar to navigate through sub views.

what is the most close approach to this in Android?

Is it to use a Tabbed Control? but this includes using just one activity.

what is the approach to use in Android to create an activity with a navigation control to other activities in a way similar to that of the iPhone?

Comment: Update: hi all, I've found another approach to do this. check my blogpost http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#CommonLayouts) for creating a "Tab Layout" on the android dev site:

> You can implement your tab content in
>   one of two ways: use the tabs to swap
>   Views within the same Activity, or use
>   the tabs to change between entirely
>   separate activities

[image: Tab Layout]
<sub>(source: [android.com](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/images/hello-tabwidget.png))</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I really don't know the iPhone, but may a QuickAction Dialog help you??

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

I imagine a list of some activities in that dialog.

I hope this is close to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of examples around

http://www.anddev.org/code-snippets-for-android-f33/iphone-tabs-for-android-t14678.html

This one is scrollable
http://code.google.com/p/mobyfactory-uiwidgets-android/

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/tabhost" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" 
>
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    />

    <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
   />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: TabHost, TabActivity etc is depreciated, isn't it?