# Android honeycomb tabs like action bar

Tags: android

And want to create tabs WITHOUT using Action bar. What will be the best thing to use for following set up ? .... on button click view panel ..... I guess I need experts help. Thanks.

Tab1 | Tab2 | Tab3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

Comment: maybe http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabsPager.html

Comment: or something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330969/iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android or: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Comment: @ rosco, That Tab Layout looks perfect. Can I use it in honeycomb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider to implement Tab Bar using an iPhone like style as explained here: [iPhone- like tab bar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330969/iphone-like-tab-bar-in-android) or using an Android style as described here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

(I transformed my comment in answer)