# Android Custom Tab Content

Tags: android, android-layout

i use this code: 
http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/

How to each tab to add content? I want to add text or button? Unfortunately I do not find how to add information to a tab. Thanks in advance for information.

Answer (score 1):

You shoud have to make One Activity in which You are extending the TabActivity. Then Create the SubActivity for the perticular TabBar section.

See this Example: [Developer Example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

For More Information see this example also:[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)

Hope it will help you.

Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Tab Layout as explained here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html and here: [Android honeycomb tabs like action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670304/android-honeycomb-tabs-like-action-bar/9670947#9670947)